# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Tags: python

I'm new to python and still trying to figure out how to make it work.  I'm on

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.8
- pip 21.3.1
- pandas 1.3.4
- requests 2.26.0
- pandas-datareader 0.10.0
- PyCharm 2021.2.3 (Community Edition)

pip list and pip show both confirm their installation and versions. At the beginning of my python script I have

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

but when I run it I receive

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

I've read various postings on the subject, but haven't found a solution.  I've tried uninstalling & reinstalling pandas_datareader with pip

```
pip uninstall pandas_datareader
pip install pandas_datareader
```

and downloaded the code with git

```
git clone https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader.git
cd pandas-datareader
python setup.py install
```

but neither solution worked... Can someone offer me a solution please?  Thanks!

**Wanted to follow up on my question... The directories with these libraries weren't included in PyCharm.... As soon as I added them the error went away**

Comment: Have you checked that the ``pip`` you used to install `pandas_datareader` actually targets the correct Python version? Did you use a bare ``pip`` or ``python -m pip``  command?

Comment: Are you sure that using same python version in IDE and check `pip list` to confirm if module is present or not and if all OK just restart your IDE

Comment: Instead of describing with words ("I've tried uninstalling & reinstalling pandas_datareader with pip and downloaded the code with git") you should show the *actual commands* that you have run. You probably should also provide information that shows *which* pip/Python is being used, e.g. the output of ``pip --version`` and ``python --version``.

Comment: MisterMiyagi
I'm unsure how to check if pip targets the correct Python version... Can you expand on this please?  And I've tried both bare pip or python -m pip command

Comment: Bhavya Parikh... I'm unsure how to check if I'm using same python version in IDE... I've checked 'pip list' and as far as I know I have the lastest versions of all the modules... But I've restarted PyCharm several times

Comment: MisterMiyagi
 I've included all the versions in the body of my question